# pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE TELEPHONY); always returning false

Tags: android, uses-feature

I am trying to check if the device has telephony feature or not. But in emulator, it is always returning false. Why is it so? Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: is this your code? pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE TELEPHONY); returning false ??? its always returning false.

Comment: I'm doing this: boolean hasTelephony=pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY); and for emulator it is returning false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6465125/1012284

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find any reason or solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect to an emulator console to simulate an incoming voice call or SMS. For more information, see Telephony Emulation and SMS Emulation.
End of this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking
That is normal, your emulator does't call nor it sends sms (note that Telephony includes a lot of features)

Answer (score -1):

You can just wrap your code in try/catch. It works in all cases, even with the last api changes about sms sending.

```
try{
    // code that use telephony features
}
catch(Exception e){
    // code that doesn't use telephony features
}
```