# App is not listed in Google play store for tablet devices

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Have published the app on the google play store. Able to download and install on android phones.
But the app is not at all listed in Play store for tablet devices.
i suspect there is something wrong in my manifest file. 
contents of the manifest file are

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Please guide me with the changes which i have to make so that the app gets listed on Play Store for Tablet devices.
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add at least one tablet screen shot?

Comment: Does the tablet have the option of inserting sim card??

Comment: adding tablet screen shots while publishing? yes, have added 5 tablet screen shots

Comment: @lal : No the tablets do not have sim option.

Comment: @Rajesh..if your tablet doesnot have simcard or memory card slot and you write some permission like "wrtie_external_storage"..so for that reason your app is not viewed on google play for your tablet.

Comment: @Nil : tablet has memory card slot. since sim card slot wont be there for some tablets permission "RECEIVE_SMS" will work ?

Comment: No its not work because this permission is not supported to your tablet...at the time of uploading your apk you will see your supported list of phones and tablets so you wl get idea about your all device.

Comment: @Nil : have removed this permission since am not using this as of now, will try publishing to store.

Comment: Ok..Thats the reason why your app doesnt show in google play store..@RajeshRs

Comment: Hi lal, please find recent changes to the manifest file above. with this configuration i am able to view the app on Samsung Galaxy Tab(And 4.0.4) where as the same is not visioble on Samsung Galaxy Tab2(And ver. 4.1.2)

Answer (score 5):

There are two reason, I know, why my app doesn't be shown on Play Store.

1. The device's OS version is lower than you specified using "minsdkversion" on Androidmanifest.xml.
2. Permission things. If you declared permissions of Phone Call, Camera etc, and Tablet that not have those hardware, Users cannot find my app on Google Play Store for their device.

So, We should add some code to Androidmanifast.xml like below.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-feature>
```

For more informations, check this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036047/536078).
,[this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering).

Answer (score 0):

After @Lal's answer i did a simple test. I added the permissions below and upload a simple apk. Manifest is like below.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.fingerprints.service.ACCESS_FINGERPRINT_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

I uploaded app to play store and i can install for tablet. Then i removed

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

and tried to update play store app and there was a warning that tablets cant download after this update. I took screenshot, may be some one can need this.

[image]

and this is details.

[image]

After published update, i could not install for tablet.