# App not shown on Playstore on TAB

Tags: android

I have developed an app to show portrait on phone and landscape on TABLETS. Strangely the App is not shown on TAB when I search on play store.

It says Designed for Phone... I have put all the details in Manifest. What else could be wrong:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

And I declare activity like this:

```
    <activity
            android:name="com.pk.imageViewer.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.imv"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
    </activity>
```

And then in **layout** folder I have mainactivity.xml and I have created another folder for TABLETS called **layout-w600dp-land** in that mainactivity.xml too.

Comment: I think you should go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979606/app-is-not-listed-in-google-play-store-for-tablet-devices

Comment: @Mani: Already seen that. If I do that I have a problem I am not able make any calls.

Comment: Checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play ?

Comment: it has not picked your layout-w600dp-land folder. its spellings are incorrect :)

Comment: it should be layout-sw600dp-land

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi: It can't be because when I run the app on tablet I can see only landscape and it can't turn to portrait.

Comment: which tablet app is not showing?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by doing

```
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Hi.. will try this and get back.. Thanks!