# Internal testing Android app installed via play store but can't find on phone

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm wanting to test my React-Native app on my physical Android device so it has all gone through the AppCenter and been released to internal testing.

I can go onto the Play Store and download the app, with it showing that I am part of the internal testing team and I am downloading a Beta version.

[image]

However, upon successful installation I cannot see the app in my app drawer and in the Play Store, I can only see the 'uninstall' button and no button to 'open' the app.

Is there something I am missing? Is it hiding somewhere I'm unaware of?

Comment: Does your app has a activity defined in AndroidManifet.xml that had an intent-filter for MAIN and LAUNCHER? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32677005/150978

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple accounts on your device and it causes this issue. Make sure you uninstall the app for all users first (you can do it via "app info") and then install it again.